# Is it possible to search using phone in foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I am new to fouresquare api. I want to built two app to search for user/business details using phone and lat/lon.
 1. Is it possible to search using phone number ?
 2. Is it possible to search using lat/lon ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [veunes/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) API endpoint to search for businesses by ll. It is not possible to search by phone number.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to search by phone using http://www.factual.com/

Comment: I have already implemented factual, but my question was about four square.